# Windows 10 sends wrong user to SMB share

Tags: windows-10, networking, nas, smb

I've got a small private network at home with several Windows 10 PCs / Laptops and a small [Qnap Nas](https://www.qnap.com/static/landing/useng/series/getstarted/) which provides a SMB access.

It worked fine so far but for two days then one of the clients can't connect to the share. From the Logs on the Qnap I see that the credentials the client sends are wrong.

I type in `user-of-nas/PW-of-user` but in the Log I see that the user submitted is the user local to the pc not the username I put in. Logging in from other clients I see the correct username in the logs, not the usernames local to the clients.

This error occurs only on this one client (win10 pro / v2004) and the login credentials work fine on all other clients.

How do I get the client to send the real credentials?

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this didn't work

Comment: Thank you. the `net use * /delete` helped. Want to make an answer?

Comment: have you try to delete the user credential cache in credential manager?

Comment: That was also one of my first ideas, but there was nothing to do with it. No hint of my NAS or the credentials used / falsely used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the machine you are connecting to the NAS SMB share from run `net use * /delete` and then rerun using syntax of the below examples for the username when prompted.

If you want to be more explicit with the deleting of the mapped network location you could use the syntax `net use \\<nas machine name>\<smb share name> /delete` instead.

**Example Syntax**

```
<name of nas machine>\<nas username>
```

or

```
.\<username>
```

The Windows 10 machine likely has a stored credential that's cached you are connecting with to the NAS SMB share, and you need to remove it and then try again. This will force it to actually use the new credential rather than the one it has cached that is not working.

---

#### Supporting Resources

- [NET USE](https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html)